# Why is one line of my PHP code interfering with the next? (Unexpected identifier error)

Tags: php

I have the following AJAX code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.questionform').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({  
            url :  "aplaygroundajaxtest.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {        
  <?php
print_r($QuestionTypePercent);  
          if($QuestionTypePercent < 100){?>
                alert("Alert Message OnClick"); 
                <?php } ?>

            },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

In the source,

```
print_r($QuestionTypePercent);  
          if($QuestionTypePercent < 100){?>
                alert("Alert Message OnClick"); 
                <?php } ?>
```

appears as `14 alert("Alert Message OnClick");` and I get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" at that line.

When I remove `print_r($QuestionTypePercent);`  the issue resolves.

Why is `print_r($QuestionTypePercent);` interfering the with the "if" condition right after it, and how do I resolve this issue? It seems as though I need some sort of break between the two lines, but I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: Are you getting that error from PHP or javascript? Where does QuestionTypePercent come from? I can't tell what you're trying to do but it seems as if you are trying to run PHP from the client side and if so you're gonna have a bad time. If you are trying to alert based on the data within the success, ditch all the php and work with the `data` variable. In regards to that ajax call, what happens within PHP stays within PHP, just like vegas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `$QuestionTypePercent` is `14`. And the output `14 alert("Alert Message OnClick");` is not valid JavaScript.

If you want to output the percent value for debugging purposes or something, I suggest you wrap it in comments, or move it into the alert.

E.g.

```
<?php if ($QuestionTypePercent < 100): ?>
    alert('Alert Message onClick: <?= $QuestionTypePercent ?>');
<?php endif ?>
```

Also note the use of the [alternative control syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). This will help make your code more readable, if you're embedding PHP, HTML and JS.

Comment: That's a great suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just enclose the print_r like this:

```
echo "/*";
print_r($QuestionTypePercent);
echo "*/";
```